# Adding multiple textviews dynamically in linear layout

Tags: xml, android-layout

I want to add multiple textviews dynamically in my app. The problem is not with adding dynamically but is in arranging them. I want the same kind of layout as in the attached image. How can I acheive this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DDFn.png)

Comment: If you want an answer with code, it is a good idea to include code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*use flexbox layout add this dependancy to your project*

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
```

*and add the layout to your xml*

```
 <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
      android:id="@+id/tagsView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:flexWrap="wrap"
      app:alignItems="stretch"
      app:alignContent="stretch"/>
```

*and in your java class*

```
 private void setUpTags() {

    tagsCount = //... integer number of textviews
    private TextView[] tags= new TextView[tagsCount];//create dynamic textviewsarray
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //loop to customize the text view and add it to flex box
    for (int i = 0; i < tagsCount; i++) {

        tags[i] = new TextView(getContext());
        GradientDrawable gD = new GradientDrawable();
        int strokeWidth = 5;
        int strokeColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.strokColor);

        gD.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        gD.setCornerRadius(15);
        gD.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

        tags[i].setBackground(gD);
        tags[i].setText("this is tag text");
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 5, 10, 5);
        tags[i].setPadding(17, 15, 17, 15);
        tagsView.addView(tags[i], layoutParams);
    }
}
```